# Can FindFit be used with units?

Tags: fitting, units

I am trying to use the units capabilities of Mathematica throughout a course that I am teaching, but am finding that it isn't uniformly implemented across many functions. In particular, I would love to be able to do the following:

```
p = (R T ρ)/M;
pressures = Quantity[{12.223, 25.20, 36.97, 60.37, 85.23, 101.3}, "kPa"];
massdensities = 
  Quantity[{0.225, 0.456, 0.664, 1.062, 1.468, 1.734}, "kg per (m m m)"];
data = {massdensities, pressures}\[Transpose];
R = Quantity["MolarGasConstant"];
T = Quantity[25 + 273.15, "Kelvins"];

FindFit[data, p, M, ρ]
```

Unfortunately, `FindFit` seems to require that everything be unitless. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, unit functionality isn't yet implemented in `FindFit`

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame, as the units functionality is quite useful, and yet my students and I are repeatedly coming across cases where we have to strip the units in order to do something, and it often takes quite some time to track down to it being the units that are the problem.

Comment: *Help > Give feedback* brings you to: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/